# Cannot set S3 as api gateway AWS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to setup a Amazon API Gateway proxy which would be connected to s3 bucket to just proxy each file/object from the bucket to the API Gateway endpoint. (I need this because i need some files to be passed through other HTTP verbs, and s3 does not allow POST method).

The thing is that I cannot select 'S3' as aws service

[image: console screenshot]

Can someone provide me some guidance?

Comment: Do you see "Simple Storage Service (S3)"?

Answer (score 0):

To allow the API to invoke required Amazon S3 actions, you must have appropriate IAM policies attached to an IAM role. The next section describes how to verify and to create, if necessary, the required IAM role and policies.

For your API to view or list Amazon S3 buckets and objects, you can use the IAM-provided AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess policy in the IAM role.

Please read documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) to know full setup

Answer (score 0):

It should be under a name **Simple Storege Service (S3)**